# How to change System Language with Powershell

Tags: powershell, automation

I have a PowerShell script that intends to change the System Locale on a Windows 10 Machine, but it doesn't really change that much, it just "downloads" the language but doesn't set it to the language, so I have to do it manually.

```
Set-Culture de-DE
Set-WinSystemLocale -SystemLocale de-DE
Set-WinUILanguageOverride -Language de-DE
Set-WinHomeLocation -GeoId 94
New-WinUserLanguageList -Language de-DE
Set-WinUserLanguageList de-DE -Force
shutdown -r;exit
```

It outputs this

```
LanguageTag     : de-DE
Autonym         : Deutsch (Deutschland)
EnglishName     : German
LocalizedName   : Deutsch (Deutschland)
ScriptName      : Lateinisch
InputMethodTips : {0407:00000407}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

UPDATE: Ok seems like it works now (not that I changed anything?) - It changed everything for the local User profile, the thing i want is that it applied to the Welcome Screen and possible New User Profiles also is it possible to change the language for non unicode programs.

UPDATE 2: Okay after some testing It just downloads the new Pack but doesn't actually apply it - when the pack had already been downloaded it applies it - my question is - How do I apply the language pack without installing it manually?

[Here you can see the Spanish language pack it says that it is available but my system language is still the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otMPe.png)

Any idea how I can automate this process?

Thanks a lot!.

Comment: from the docs, it looks like you should be capturing what's returned from `New-WinUserLanguageList` and then passing that into `Set-WinUserLanguageList` -- does the script output anything when it runs (maybe omit the shutdown and exit commands while testing?)

Comment: @TZHX Yes it does, how do I pass it to Set-WinUserLanguageList? I put the Output into my post!

Comment: Ok seems like it works now - It changed everything for the local User profile, the thing i want is that it applied to the Welcome Screen and possible New User Profiles also is it possible to change the language for non unicode programms.

Comment: Automate it how?

Comment: Via powershell!